# mount times out with iptables --policy OUTPUT DROP

Tags: centos, mount, iptables, firewall, cifs

I previously ACCEPTed all output traffic by default.  Recently changed the policy to DENY output by default, only opening ports needed for server/application functionality.

When I tried to mount a drive this morning, there was a timeout (the destination server is up).  If I set the output policy to ACCEPT, I'm able to mount without issue.

I've added the following rules to my firewall:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 166 packets, 49616 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:137 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
  628 48984 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:137 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:138 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
   32  7244 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:138 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:139 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spt:139 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 30 packets, 1800 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:137 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:137 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:138 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:138 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    3   180 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:139 state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:139 state NEW,ESTABLISHED
```

By temporarily setting output to ACCEPT, I generated some INPUT traffic on ports  udp:137, udp:138.   I see some OUPUT traffic on tcp:139.

The second I change default output to DENY, I get timeouts again.

Here's the `/etc/fstab` line:

> //example.com/shares/acoder   /mnt/acoder cifs    credentials=/etc/credfile,dom=example,uid=0,gid=0,file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0700
>   0 0   0   0

In the example above, //example.com/shares/acoder is a Windows server.

Here's the relevant portion of `/etc/services`

```
# grep -i NETBIOS /etc/services 
netbios-ns      137/tcp                         # NETBIOS Name Service
netbios-ns      137/udp
netbios-dgm     138/tcp                         # NETBIOS Datagram Service
netbios-dgm     138/udp
netbios-ssn     139/tcp                         # NETBIOS session service
netbios-ssn     139/udp
```

What other port(s) need to be open for mounting with `cifs`?

Comment: In general, if you want to see what network traffic is hitting a chain's default policy having a `iptables -I ChainName -j LOG` will help you figure that out which will in turn let you know which ports to open up. For example, in your case `iptables -I INPUT -j LOG` and `iptables -I INPUT -j LOG`

Comment: Did you mean `iptables -I INPUT -j LOG` and `iptables -I OUTPUT -j LOG`?

Comment: Er yeah, I guess that's what I get for copying and pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need port 445 and make sure that you also have incoming related/established traffic allowed.

```
grep 445 /etc/services
microsoft-ds    445/tcp             # Microsoft Naked CIFS
microsoft-ds    445/udp
```